# how to create a regex that starts with a specific letter and ends with x amount of numbers

Tags: python, regex, scrapy

I'm trying to create a particular regex, and it wouldn't come out. The idea is to build a regex that starts with the letter 'a', 'b', or 'c' and is followed by five random numbers. You can't have anything ahead or behind. The idea is to scrape GitHub files looking for this particular pattern

valid examples:

```
1) a454744 = a454744
2) lalala: a787878 = a787878
3) b121351 lalala = b121351
4) lalala:c454545
```

Invalid examples:

```
1) aa454744
2) a1234567
3) c454545lalala
```

What I have

```
\b[abc]\d{5}$|^[abc]\d{5}$
```

Comment: You say `You can't have anything ahead or behind.` but then you say `lalala: a787878 = a787878` is valid which has things both ahead and behind. You also say you want 5 digits, but all your valid examples have 6 digits.

Comment: You don't need the alternative with `^`, since `\b` matches the beginning of line.

Comment: @Mark I think they mean you can't have any non-whitespace ahead or behind.

Comment: There are 6 digits instead of 5 `(?<!\S)[abc]\d{6}(?!\S)` https://regex101.com/r/4xYwPn/1

Comment: All of your "valid examples" have 6 digits.

Comment: This matches all your examples (assuming you mean 6 digits): `\b[abc]\d{6}\b`

Comment: Sorry, the amount of numbers does not matter if they are 5 or 6. I am using this regex
[abc]{1}[0-9]{5}
and I am having these events as valid which are wrong
aaa88888 (it shouldn't take it even though my regex is included in that string), but I can't add the string start condition because if I have a pattern similar to this lalala: a99999 I should take it the same and in that case I wouldn't, sorry if I don't I expressed myself well, thank you all the same for helping me :)

Comment: You have some answers (in my comment above and in the answer below). you can require 5 or 6 digits using the pattern `{5,6}` instead of `{5}` or `{6}`. How about trying these out?

Comment: thanks gavia for the comment, the problem here does not come from the numbers that I want my regex to have, but from the fact that I don't know how to make my regex not match when it is included in a string of this characteristic aa12345 (this case would be invalid), but If I add the character ^ at the beginning of the string, it will not match a pattern of this type that would be valid (lalala: a12345). Maybe I'm not understanding some concept but it's kind of hard to explain haha

Answer (score 1):

^[abc]\d{5}$

- ^: beginning of string
- [abc]: match "a", "b", or "c"
- \d: digit
- {5}: match previous smybol 5 times
- $: end of string

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex pattern. It matches all the valid cases in your description and does not match the invalid cases in your description.

`\b[abc]\d{5,6}\b`

- \b assert position at a word boundary
- [abc] match a single character in the list (case sensitive)
- \d{5,6} match a digit [0-9] Between 5 and 6 times, as many times as possible

Comment: Hi topsail, thanks for your feedback. I also think that the regular expression you say works well, what's more, I've tried it in online regex, but when I try to do it in python there is something with those '\b' that they don't like to and it doesn't match me with anything, I should look for an alternative for that \b :(

Comment: make sure you are using a raw string for your regex patterns (this is the typical solution to avoid backslash problems in python regex). So, for example `match = re.search(r'\b[abc]\d{5,6}\b', my_text_to_match)` More info here: [the-backslash-plague](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#the-backslash-plague)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the extra information you provided in the comments, try this:

`[^A-Za-z][abc]\d{5,6}`